# Looping Through Arrays of Structs in AudioKit

Tags: swift, audiokit

I'm trying to create MIDI content for sequencer playback by using an array of structs.  Each struct creates a 'measure', and each measure has properties of location, numberOfBeats, and tempo.  I'd like to loop through each measure for each beat within the measure, and play one of two MIDI notes based on whether the beat is the first in the measure or not.

The code below will print correctly (click1, click 2, click2, click1, click 2, click1, click2, click2), however the MIDI content (attached to a wav) will only play once through and not advance to the next measure in the array.  I've been trying to get the func to work it's way sequentially through the array of measures using a variety of loop types, but can't get it to progress correctly.  Thanks!

```
import UIKit
import AudioKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

let sequencer = AKSequencer ()

var metronomeTrack1: AKMusicTrack!
var metronomeTrack2: AKMusicTrack!

let click1 = AKMIDISampler()
let click2 = AKMIDISampler ()

func setupTracks() {
    metronomeTrack1 = sequencer.newTrack()
    metronomeTrack1?.setMIDIOutput(click1.midiIn)
    metronomeTrack2 = sequencer.newTrack()
    metronomeTrack2?.setMIDIOutput(click2.midiIn)
}

struct Measure {
    var location : Int
    var numberOfBeats : Int
    var tempo : Int
}

var measureOne = Measure(location: 1, numberOfBeats: 4, tempo: 100)
var measureTwo = Measure(location: 2, numberOfBeats: 2, tempo: 100)
var measureThree = Measure(location: 3, numberOfBeats: 4, tempo: 100)

var arrayIndex = [Measure]()

//Variables to track location through loops
var arrayLocator = 0
var beatWatcher = 0

func playMeasures () {

for _ in arrayIndex {
    for beats in 0...(arrayIndex[arrayLocator].numberOfBeats - 1) {

        if beatWatcher == 0 {
            metronomeTrack1?.add(noteNumber: 60, velocity: 100, position: AKDuration(beats: Double(beats)), duration: AKDuration(beats: 1))
            print("click1")
            beatWatcher += 1

        } else {
            metronomeTrack2?.add(noteNumber: 60, velocity: 100, position: AKDuration(beats: Double(beats)), duration: AKDuration(beats: 1))
            print("click2")
            beatWatcher += 1

            if beatWatcher == (arrayIndex[arrayLocator].numberOfBeats) {
                beatWatcher = 0
                arrayLocator += 1
            }
        }
    }
 }
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    arrayIndex = [measureOne, measureTwo, measureThree]

    metronomeTrack1?.clear()
    metronomeTrack2?.clear()
    sequencer.setLength(AKDuration(beats: 100))

    AudioKit.output = click1
    AudioKit.output = click2

    setupTracks()

    try! click1.loadWav("blockhigh")
    try! click2.loadWav("blocklow")

    playMeasures()
    sequencer.play()
    try!AudioKit.start()
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After further research; looks like using stride is the best way to work through the loops, and the "position" in each MIDI track needs to increment by 1 each loop to get added to the sequence in proper order.